# javascript - window.open within XMLHttpRequest onreadystatechange anon. function

Tags: javascript

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
httpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpReq.readyState == 4) {
        if (httpReq.status == 200) {
            var response = httpReq.responseText;
            if (response == "-2") document.shortener_form.urlField.value = "";
            else {
                document.shortener_form.urlField.value = response;
                window.open("http://example.com", '_blank');
            }
        } else {
            document.shortener_form.urlField.value = "Error!";
        }
    }
};
```

The `window.open` function on line 8 is not executing. It works everywhere else, just not within that anonymous function. I'm terrible at Javascript, I've searched Google and SO however found no answer. Thanks.

**Edit:** by the way, the function works everywhere else on the page and script, so I've isolated the problem to be within this anonymous function.

Comment: Is window.open() being triggered by a user click everywhere else where it is working? Might be popup blocker or browser settings that are preventing the window from opening unless directly as a result of a user click.

Comment: It works everywhere else, just not within the anon. function. (It doesn't work ANYWHERE within the anon function).

Comment: I know it works everywhere else, but I am asking if the window.open() function is being triggered by a user click everywhere else.

Comment: Oh sorry! The user clicks on a button, which triggers a function that performs the XMLHttpRequest. The function that executes the HTTP request contains this function. So in a way, yes it is triggered by a user.

Comment: I think that might be the problem. Your browser doesn't want to open a window unless it was caused directly by a user click.

Comment: @jessegavin, great call! That was exactly the problem. I've disabled the pop-up blocker and it worked. Obviously, this is not what I want, but still. I'll work on a different solution then. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a solution without the pop-up blocker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a popup blocker problem. Your browser doesn't want to allow `window.open()` unless it is the direct result from a user action (e.g. mouse click).

Answer (score 1):

This may be a browser setting.  Most browsers these days default to blocking popups (i.e. calls to `window.open`) that aren't triggered by a user-initiated event.  This would cause popups to work inside e.g. a click or keyup handler, but not within an asynchronously-triggered function like your ready-state handler.

Check to see whether `window.open` works in other asynchronous code:

```
<script>
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.open("http://example.com", '_blank');
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

If this fails in your browser (as it does in mine), you're probably running into a popup blocker.

Comment: Any work around for that? basically my report show up as part of an ajax call!

Answer (score 0):

Is this line being executed or throwing an error:
`document.shortener_form.field.value = response;`

I noticed that it's different from the lines above and below it:
`document.shortener_form.**urlField**.value = "";` (note the *'s) was that intentional?

Comment: it is being executed. I've isolated the issue, and the problem is with the `window.open` function. Any other operation within the `if` statements work properly.

Comment: @Tekin: Perhaps it's what you're passing to it as the second parameter. `_blank` is a reserved target and so you can't name your window that. The `window.open` already defaults to opening in a new window anyway, as far as I know. Check out the Mozilla [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) on it for more info on the parameters. **Edit** Just to be clear, the second parameter is not the target for the window, it's just a name you can use to reference the window later.

Comment: I'm trying to open it in a separate tab (or window if tabs not supported). It works everywhere else properly, and just as I want it to, however does not work within the anonymous function.

Comment: @Tekin: I see. I found the spot in the docs where they reference that. What browser are you using and does it work in other browsers?